# Can't hide val from supertype constructor

Tags: kotlin, constructor, properties, arguments, member

I have a class that extends a parent class like this:

```
abstract class BaseClass(val mem: Type)

class MyClass(val mem: Type) : BaseClass(mem)
```

I've declared the member as an argument of the constructor on `MyClass` because the `BaseClass` it extends from requires something be passed in, however this doesn't work because the compiler tells me that `mem` "hides member of supertype". I want this argument to be a member of the `BaseClass`, hence the use of `val`. How do I pass through the argument from `MyClass`?

Answer (score 1):

While the argument in the constructor of `BaseClass` should be a `val`, the argument in the constructor of `MyClass` doesn't need to be. This is because it can just be an argument in the constructor that isn't part of the object. Since it is passed to `BaseClass` where it becomes a property of the object, and is, by definition, available in `MyClass`:

`class MyClass(mem: Type) : BaseClass(mem)`